# why left panel is not display on whole screen .?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

i am making a panel  for my screen.As we saw in all in all android and desktop application.which display on whole height.Actually my panel is display only on half of the screen .
I increase "z-index",and change position to relative but both not work I want to panel to whole height which should come through animate (animation is working ) but it is not is whole height.

you can check on my fiddle .
http://jsfiddle.net/vfuR7/1/
There is **">>"** button you click it it open the panel .but small height.
If I used jquery mobile it not clickable.

```
.panel {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    height:550px;
    background:#d9dada;
    position:relative;
    left:-80%;

}
.slider-arrow {
    padding:5px;
    width:10px;
    float:left;
    background:#d9dada;
    font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    left:-80%;
}
```

Comment: The panel looks like it reaches the bottom to me.

Comment: i solve the problem using JQM

Answer (score -1):

> i think you can solve this by using below steps

- give proper height values.
  For eg: parent container = 100%;
- append child to parent
- use jquery 1.8.3